# How to get a value of Object which possible has a undefined key?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

something like `angular`'s `$parse` service.

If there is an object like this:

```js
const obj = {
  items: [
    {
      store: {
        type: ''
      }
    }
  ]
};
```

**watch**: the keys `items` and `store` and `type` possible are `undefined`, or no exist.

I want to get the first `item`'s type, here is my code:

```js
const firstItem = obj.items[0] || {};
const store = firstItem.store || {};
const type = store.type || 'computer';
```

I think there is a better way to do this. I know `angular`'s `$parse` service is simple to do that. Is there a way like `angular`'s `$parse` service or any other ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Something like [Lodash's `_.get`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.15.0#get) ~ `_.get(obj, 'items[0].store.type', 'computer')`

Comment: I want to do it just use `javascript`

Comment: You know Lodash is just JavaScript, right? In any case, you can always look at the source for `_.get` for some inspiration

Comment: I mean **library free**. I know `underscore`, `lodash`, many libraries have util function can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not to use try catch.

```
var type;
try {
    type = obj.items[0].store.type;
}
catch {
    type = 'computer';
}
```

Comment: Nope. It's quite straight forward solution.

Comment: @novaline, if it helped you, then mark this as answer, so other people may use it.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!angular.isUndefined(obj))
{
   if(angular.isArray(obj.items)){
       // Do something
   }
}
```

Is there you need ?

Comment: No, he needs to check `type` obviously.

Comment: ah , sorry. My bad